# Auto Concatenate oracle column based on row value without using case condition

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

how to concatenate select column name based on each row block sequence value without using case condition.
refer the picture

Serial num column is the finalized of different concatenated column.

Oracle Query :

```
SELECT Z.*, 
       (CASE WHEN BLOCK_SEQUENCE = 'SERIAL_PREFIX,CURRENT_RUN_NUM'
                  THEN (SERIAL_PREFIX || CURRENT_RUN_NUM)
             WHEN BLOCK_SEQUENCE = 'SERIAL_PREFIX,CURRENT_RUN_NUM,OPTION1' 
                  THEN (SERIAL_PREFIX || CURRENT_RUN_NUM || OPTION1)
             WHEN BLOCK_SEQUENCE = 'SERIAL_PREFIX,OPTION1,OPTION2,OPTION3,CURRENT_RUN_NUM'
                  THEN (SERIAL_PREFIX || OPTION1 || OPTION2 || OPTION3 || CURRENT_RUN_NUM)
       END) SERIAL_NUM
  FROM (SELECT SERIAL_PREFIX, OPTION1, OPTION2, OPTION3, RUN_NUM_LENGTH, CURRENT_RUN_NUM CURRENT_NUM, BLOCK_SEQUENCE, LPAD(CURRENT_RUN_NUM,RUN_NUM_LENGTH, '0') CURRENT_RUN_NUM
          FROM (SELECT 'SKR' SERIAL_PREFIX, '23' OPTION1, 'A' OPTION2, 'M'OPTION3, '6'RUN_NUM_LENGTH, '11'CURRENT_RUN_NUM,
'SERIAL_PREFIX,OPTION1,OPTION2,OPTION3,CURRENT_RUN_NUM' BLOCK_SEQUENCE
                  FROM DUAL
                 UNION
                SELECT 'SKU' SERIAL_PREFIX, '.2' OPTION1, '' OPTION2, '' OPTION3, '5' RUN_NUM_LENGTH, '200'CURRENT_RUN_NUM, 'SERIAL_PREFIX,CURRENT_RUN_NUM, OPTION1' BLOCK_SEQUENCE 
                  FROM DUAL
                 UNION
                SELECT 'SKA' SERIAL_PREFIX, '' OPTION1, '' OPTION2, '' OPTION3, '5' RUN_NUM_LENGTH, '41' CURRENT_RUN_NUM, 'SERIAL_PREFIX,CURRENT_RUN_NUM' BLOCK_SEQUENCE
                  FROM DUAL
               )
       ) Z;
```

[image]

I'm expecting to have a dynamic concatenate column **instead of putting case condition** every time.
Is there any solution for this requirement?

Comment: Please try "WITH" clause in SQL. If that is getting complex then try to write PL/SQL Block then take value into TEMP table and then display into the FINAL table.

Comment: `select ..., replace(replace(...replace(BLOCK_SEQUENCE, 'SERIAL_PREFIX', SERIAL_PREFIX), 'CURRENT_RUN_NUM', CURRENT_RUN_NUM), ...)`